# Check registery key value on multiple clients

Tags: windows-registry

Is there any way or a tool to check a specific registry key value, for multiple clients 
on a network almost 2000 pc ?

Thanks

Comment: do you have powershell available to you?

Comment: yes its available

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [reg](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/reg.mspx?mfr=true) combined with [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).

Comment: can you tell me how ?